# Display full article using ajax through readmore

Tags: joomla, module, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5

Basically joomla articles show excerpt and a readmore link. Upon click the readmore the the full page loads. But can the full text be loaded on the same box when readmore is clicked. As in a slider using ajax?

Is there any module or plugin that already does this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this extension - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/site-performance/13293